# Gitlab CI shared runner won't start

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to use Gitlab.com shared runner, and I have added my `gitlab-ci.yml` file into my repo. My project is configured to use Shared Runners (in Settings ➔ CI/CD), but the pipeline page does not show any job when I push commits.

I tried to follow official docs, and none of the previous stackoverflow answers are helping. This is the contents of my `gitlab-ci.yml`

```
.nodejs_runners:
  variables:
    NODE_ENV: 'development'
  cache:
    key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    paths:
      - /**/node_modules
  before_script:
    - yarn --frozen-lockfile --non-interactive --silent
  image: node:12
  tags:
    - docker

stages:
  - test

build-frontend:
  extends:
    - .nodejs_runners
  when: always
  stage: test
  script:
    - NODE_ENV="production" yarn build
    - tar -zcvf frontend-$CI_COMMIT_SHA.tar.gz .next
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - frontend-$CI_COMMIT_SHA.tar.gz
```

My repo is public and you can [view it here](https://gitlab.com/trao/thilak.dev/-/blob/master/gitlab-ci.yml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/

GitLab CI/CD pipelines are configured using a YAML file called `.gitlab-ci.yml` within each project.

Your `.gitlab-ci.yml` is called `gitlab-ci.yml`, which is why GitLab can't find it.

Rename `gitlab-ci.yml` to `.gitlab-ci.yml` and GitLab will pick it up.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I made such a silly mistake 

Comment: No worries. I’ve made the same mistake myself. You are welcome!